# sql distinct function trouble

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a query

```
 SELECT   m1.mid mid, m1.uid uid, m1.date, m1.body body
 FROM messages  m1
 WHERE m1.chat_id IS NULL  
   and deleted = 0  
   AND m1.date in    
    ( 
       SELECT MAX(m2.date) 
       FROM messages m2   
       WHERE m2.uid = m1.uid 
         AND m2.chat_id IS NULL 
         and m2.deleted = 0  
    )
```

This query was not actually written by me, I got help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111766/cant-agregate-on-max-function) - hanks them a lot.

But I have a problem. When there is more than one message with the same date and uid(from the same user) values,  i get two or more records with the same date and uid, but i'd like to have only one( no matter which, or the message with the greatest mid f.e.)

I've tried to use distinct(uid) with no success result. Is there any other way to achive the result i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution to find the most recent message per `uid`:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(mid) AS maxmid
    FROM messages
    WHERE chat_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY uid
) a
INNER JOIN messages b ON a.maxmid = b.mid
```

Comment: Still wrong. http://c.kurganec.ru/p/jxvT0ci.png there are records with the same uid. THanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for the most recent message per uid?

Comment: Great! Oh and one more thing, is `mid` an autoincrementing column?

Comment: Let's assume that yes. I can't be sure because i get them through rest api, but ids looks like autoincremented

Answer (score 0):

Rather you could add an extra column "count" and display the number of messages from a user on the same day!!

By this you can avoid, getting duplicate records!

Comment: First of all, it is actually not the same day it is the same seconds. And second i really didn't get the profit of adding new column.

Comment: If I am right, your subquery is returning multiple rows. You should also select the maximum of the mid so that you get the latest record.